# htop: any way to see a sorted tree view from a sub level?

Tags: process, process-management, htop

When using `htop`, I generally find that viewing process sorted by `RES` makes most sense when looking for performance and other issues in macOS.  One problem I have is that `Google Chrome` (and other processes) are now spawning many sub-processes and so a combined Sorted+Tree view would be extremely helpful.

For example, I want to see all processes that are using the most memory, BUT I also want to see their children.  I DON'T want to see the primary parent tree structure that normal `Tree` view provides (ie, `kernel_task` -> `launchd` -> etc. etc. etc.) - this just doesn't really work like we need now with things like Chrome going nuts on the spawned processes and being able to find and kill that singular process, especially when using tools like `Epichrome` to have many instances of Chrome (exceptionally useful by the way), or apps like Rambox, Franz, and many others...

Any way to accomplish this kind of view into system processes currently?